# How to find values in certain DataFrame columns that are greater/smaller than a given maximum, and then replace them with the previous row's values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe df has columns "Datetime" and "A", "B", "C" that contain some temperatures as float values:

```
abctemps = {"Datetime": ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05"],
            "A": [1.0,4.5,8.0,11.1,100.2],
            "B": [-5.0,-18.1,-7.3,-5000.3,-21.5],
            "C": [4,87,3.0,7,81]}
df = pd.DataFrame(abctemps)
df

    Datetime    A        B      C
0   2018-01-01  1.0     -5.0    4.0
1   2018-01-02  4.5     -18.1   87.0
2   2018-01-03  8.0     -7.3    3.0
3   2018-01-04  11.1    -5000.3 7.0
4   2018-01-05  100.2   -21.5   81.0
```

Columns A, B and C contain temperatures but **some values are clearly too large** (or small) **to be true** (100.2, -5000.3, 87, 81), **so I want to replace them with the previous** (or next in case previous doesn't exist?) **value in the same column**. So for example in column A, 100.2 would be replaced with 11.1. Or in column B, -5000.3 with -7.3.

**Desired output would look like this:**

```
    Datetime    A        B      C
0   2018-01-01  1.0     -5.0    4.0
1   2018-01-02  4.5     -18.1   4.0
2   2018-01-03  8.0     -7.3    3.0
3   2018-01-04  11.1    -7.3    7.0
4   2018-01-05  11.1    -21.5   7.0
```

I'm thinking of a function that:

1. filters to show only the rows in a given column where the value is greater than for example 40,
2. grabs that row's `.loc`
3. based on that `.loc`, grabs the previous row's value in the same column
4. replaces the bad value with that previous row's value

How would I do this, or is there another way that is better? Is `.loc` good for this? Thank you for any help.

**edit: I was able to make a function that does this:**

```
def longtozero(col, length):
    try:
        df.loc[df[col].str.len() > length, col] = df.loc[df.loc[df[col].str.len() > length, col].index[0]-1, col]
        df[col] = df[col].astype('float64')
    except:
        pass
```

Then call the function with the column and the desired maximum length, for example:

```
longtozero("A", 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by detecting outliers in each column. Here's a way to do so:

```
m = df.loc[:,:'C'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x-x.mean()) <= (x.std()), axis=0)

     A      B      C
0   True   True   True
1   True   True  False
2   True   True   True
3   True  False   True
4  False   True  False
```

And then use boolean indexing and use both [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) to make sure you fill all missing values:

```
df.loc[:,:'C'] = df.loc[:,:'C'].where(m).ffill().bfill()

     A     B    C    Datetime
0   1.0  -5.0  4.0  2018-01-01
1   4.5 -18.1  4.0  2018-01-02
2   8.0  -7.3  3.0  2018-01-03
3  11.1  -7.3  7.0  2018-01-04
4  11.1 -21.5  7.0  2018-01-05
```

Comment: If I copypaste the first line (m = df.loc[:,:'C'].apply(lambda x: abs(x) < abs(x).quantile(0.8), axis=0)), it gives a TypeError: ("bad operand type for abs(): 'str'", 'occurred at index Datetime'). This is in case dtype of "Datetime" is 'object' - if I first change it to datetime64, the first line gives TypeError: ("ufunc 'absolute' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Comment: Try with the update, using another method to remove outliers. Its working fine fo rme

Comment: The update gives error TypeError: ('Could not convert 2018-01-012018-01-022018-01-032018-01-042018-01-05 to numeric', 'occurred at index Datetime'). If "Datetime" is datetime64 instead of object, then the error is TypeError: ("reduction operation 'mean' not allowed for this dtype", 'occurred at index Datetime').

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same df you've shared here? Or the same column order? Note that the way I slice `df`, `df.loc[:,:'C']`, is assuming that the datetime column is at the end. Just as you shared

Comment: I got it to work when using df.loc[:,"A":"C"]. In the example I gave, the "Datetime" column is the first column and not at the end? But it works with "A":"C" so thank you very much for your help! If anyone wants to share other ways to do the same thing I would also be interested (.abs, .std, .ffill and .bfill in this solution are completely new to me and I'm also curious if this could be done with more "basic" methods such as filtering and .loc)